# Is there a programmatic way or eclipse plugin to calculate big O notation for java method

Tags: java, algorithm, eclipse-plugin, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Is there a programmatic way or eclipse plugin to calculate big-O notation for  java method ?

Comment: There may be a plugin, but if not then you can try keeping track of method calls and manually compute (or at least approximate) the running complexity.

Comment: I haven't tried them but it seems [metrics](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/) and [checkstyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net) plugins have cyclomatic complexity computation features

Comment: Keep in mind though, that when calculating complexity, you should be aiming for simple expression, e.g. O (n^2) rather than O (3n^2 + 2n +1)

Comment: This isn't generally possible.  In many cases proving the complexity of algorithms requires a lot of smarts that a program can't really provide.

Comment: Why would anyone close this question?  It seems like the kind of question you'd want asked and properly answered. Clearly the question shows a misunderstanding of asymptotic analysis but that doesn't mean it doesn't deserve a good answer that others could benefit from.  @LouisWasserman - why don't you turn your comment into a slightly more developed answer?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino cyclomatic complexity and run-time complexity analysis are two very different metrics. As Louis Wasserman commented, determining the run-time complexity of an algorithm in all but the most basic of cases will require some abstract reasoning that cannot be achieved by a computer - see Halting Problem which is undecidable - and you can see why.

Comment: @MikeDinescu I didn't imply that it should be calculated by computer. Quite the opposite actually - I said that in O(g(x)), g(x) should be roughly in the same ball park as the precise complexity function, be it algorithmically solvable or not.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino, I apologize, I meant to reply to the comment above yours

Comment: @MikeDinescu If anybody tried codility challenges codility.com/programmers/challenges they are evaluating your solution against performance using big O notation , and I'm sure that they are not doing this calculation manually, that's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't such plugin, and if it was, it would be a mere approximation. Namely, even determining whether the program will finish running or not is intractable - see [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Now, about the possible approximation. Let's say you have a plugin that tests your program with a small dataset (e.g. `N = 1000`) and a medium dataset (e.g. `N = 10000`). If your program runs 10 times longer with a medium dataset compared to a small dataset, plugin should conclude that your program is `O(N)`, right? Not quite. What about best/average/worst case? For example, quicksort's worst case is `O(N^2)`, but it is generally considered as `O(N*logN)` sorting algorithm. Therefore, if the plugin hits the special input, it will give a wrong result. What about constants? The program whose running time is `O(N + k*logN)` is considered `O(N)`, but if a constant `k` is large enough compared to `N`, plugin would not be able to reach this conclusion, etc.

Regarding your comment:

> If anybody tried codility challenges
>   they are evaluation your solution
>   against performance using big O notation , and I'm sure that they are
>   not calculation it manually, that's why I'm asking this question.

Authors of Codility challenges have solutions of their problems with a well-known time complexity (they analyzed it manually). When they measure the running time of your solution for various input and compare it with a running time of their solutions for the same input, they can *automatically* determine the time complexity of your program (of course, taking into account the programming language you have chosen and certain deviations of the measured time).